# Expand/Collapse Menu in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menu

I want to know if its possible to create expand/collapse sidebar menu.
For example

[image]

If you guys have any examples/ Any Suggestions on where to start.
Thank You.

Comment: To which platform you need this? (WPF / Silverlight / WP7 / Xaml)?

Comment: You can do it using expander Control .

Comment: Thanks ethicallogics, I will try Expander Control.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="Menu" Width="100" Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock>Menu 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Menu 2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Menu 3</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray">
        <Button Content="Expand/Collapse" Click="ButtonClick" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Menu.Visibility = this.Menu.Visibility == Visibility.Visible
                                ? Visibility.Collapsed
                                : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I am going to try Expander and your method.